# How does forecast analytic in Power BI work?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created the following forecast, Where:

```
Total Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Amount]), Data[Operation] = "SALE")
Total Sales Return = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Amount]), Data[Operation] = "Return")
Sales Return Ratio = DIVIDE([Total Sales Return], [Total Sales])
```

[image]

I need to understand while Sales and Sales Return trends being stable in the forecast, why is Sales Return Ratio is going up?

What is the behind the scene logic for predicting forecast in Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft writes about it [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/describing-the-forecasting-models-in-power-view/).

They use an [Exponential Smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) algorithm. I did a quick comparison and it seems to be the same algorithm used in Excel's `FORECAST.ETS()` where `ETS` stands *for Exponential Triple Smoothing*.

I will not even try to explain that algorithm here, but I found this [blog post](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/01/29/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting/) that looks promising.